# Exceptional sheaves and double dual

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In his beautiful paper *Moduli of bundles on* $K_3$ *surfaces*, Mukai proves that if $F$ is a rigid (i.e. $\mathrm{Ext}^1(F,F) = 0$) torsion free sheaf on a surface $S$ with $|-K_S| \neq 0$, then $F^{**}$, the double dual of $F$, is also rigid.

Is there any hope to have an analogous statement on higher dimensional varieties. I am thinking to the following statement :

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety with $|-K_X| \neq 0$ (perhaps a stronger hypothesis needed) and let $F$ be a torsion free sheaf such that $F$ is exceptional (that is $\mathrm{Hom}(F,F) = \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathrm{Ext^{i}}(F,F) = 0$ for $i>0$). Then the double dual of $F$ is rigid.

I would also be very interested by any counter-example.